# Rails postgres wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ubuntu, elf

I'm using rails 3.2.13, ruby 2.0 and Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit.

Bundler nagged me to use bundle install --no-deployment and I started getting this whenever I ran the rails server

```
/home/vincent/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require': /home/vincent/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg_ext.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 - /home/vincent/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg_ext.so (LoadError)
```

This might have something to do with me using a 64 bit OS but it was just working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to just do

```
bundle install --deployment
```

And it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same issue before I made groups in the gem file.

I would need to see your Gemfile to be sure,

But I am guessing you just need make groups for testing, development and production.

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

group :development do
  gem "bullet"
  gem "pry-rails"
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
end

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Once you have your grouping setup you can uses commands like

```
bundle install --development

or

bundle install --without production
```